# Trying to go to the definition of class/function in vim

Tags: vim, tags, definition

i have installed vim 7.2 and ctags 5.8 and created the tags file with "ctags -R /foopath".

I have *many methods that are called with the same name* in several classes, so if i put the cursor in a function calling and i execute ":tag" it shows the *first* of the tags listed. If the i execute ":tn" several times i finally find the method..

So my question is: is there any way to show  *directly*  the path where is the class that contains the right method I'm calling?

Answer (score 3):

`:tselect tagname` will give you a list of matching tags, and you can enter the number of the tag you want.

`:stselect tagname` will split the window first.

You can also put the cursor on a word and enter `g]` to get a list of tags matching that word.

`<CTRL-W>]` will split the window and go to the first tag matching the word under the cursor.

`<CTRL-W>g]` will split the window and give you the list of matches.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but i think you didn't understand me or maybe i didn't explain right.

Let see: imagine i have tagged several classes (class1, class2, class3, etc) that have the method foo().

If i have this code:

$class3_object = new class3();
class3_object->foo();

I'd like to go _directly_ to the tag corresponding to the class3, because it is the class of the object "class3_object".


Javi

Answer (score 0):

You can read the raw data from the tags into a buffer with taglist().  Then you can search in the buffer for other criteria that you're interested in, including class names and parts of the file directory.

So to have a more refined search for "mytag" try:

```
:new | put =taglist(\"^mytag$\")
```

To get the most information, be sure to use [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

After you search for the data you want, you'll see the file name associated with the tag prefixed with ***'filename':*** and the line text prefixed with ***'cmd':***.

Putting it in a function with some code to beautify and handle the buffer properly:

```
" List information about matching tags in a buffer
function! BrowseTags(tagStr)
  new [Tag Brower]
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap

  put =taglist(a:tagStr)

  " Beautify it a little
  normal 1G
  while search('^{', 'W')
    call setline(".", split(getline("."), "\\(\\(}$\\)\\|\\('\\w\\+':\\)\\)\\@="))
  endw
  normal 1G
endfunc
```

You can use ***call BrowseTags("^myTag$")*** to run the function for an exact match of ***myTag***, or use some regular expression to get similar matches.

Although I've never bothered to do it, it's not too difficult to write various commands automate your most common tasks without opening a buffer.